# Does psyllium husk work differently on human body when consumed with different temperature of water? If yes, what are the reasons behind it?

Tags: research, water, gastroenterology

There are some health benefits always discussed about psyllium husk. Such as described [here](https://www.nhs.uk/medicines/fybogel-ispaghula-husk/) and [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6358997/).

Now some people on social media spread myths like it works better with yoghurt. It works better with milk.

Some say it improves different issues in body when consumed with milk and different issues when consumed with yoghurt and different with water.

For example, I tried to search like "can you take it with cold water / hot water etc." and I found sources like this on Quora and similar results:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-more-beneficial-with-Isabgol-milk-or-water

This article has actually doctors responding to queries:

https://www.practo.com/consult/isabgol-with-warm-water-immediately-do-i-need-to-take-isabgol-with-warm-water-at-night-immediately-after-mixing-it/q

But they don't talk about temperature of water. When you read doctors' response, it feels like they also read answers on Quora and responding accordingly.

So I really doubt them or at least can't assume it is scientifically backed. But that is too broad to discuss it here. **I want to focus it on working of psyllium husk with different temperatures of water only.**

I have also read on some articles (now I can't find it) that it works differently when consumed with very cold water, lukewarm water and hot water. However those articles don't mention and scientific studies or proof.

So I'm looking for the same. **Are there any studies or facts which prove different temperature of water makes psyllium husk work differently on human body?**

Comment: Have you tried finding them? Where did you look? What did you search for?

Comment: @CareyGregory I've added some. But in short, I couldn't find anything specific when I did my research before asking this question. The only source is local doctors or online doctors and articles written on Quora.

What I'm looking for is some fact based study or research or any trustworthy official site like CDC / NHS which talks about temperature of water. So I could probably evaluate what people claim might be actually myths or not.

Comment: There is only [Grade B](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3124652/) evidence that psyllium actually [treats constipation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8191753/). The recent (2021) systematic review makes no mention of temperature which matches my search results. I can find no evidence of medical studies assessing the effect of temperature of ingestion and would not expect one given the general lack of medical studies on psyllium.

Comment: @IanCampbell that link is helpful.

Comment: @IanCampbell regarding treatment of constipation, I don't know about treatment of ongoing chronic constipation, but it definitely helps solve some gut problems for many people, like mild constipation. That is why it's widely known. But that is a different topic to ask question on.